# Putting values into an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Below is the current code I am using to loop though and update a table. However, I am having issues with getting the array defined correctly. The array is getting value from an HTML form before them then being updated to the table.

```
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT min(leagueID) AS minLeagueID, max(leagueID) AS maxLeagueID , leageuID , trackID FROM leagueTracks WHERE legueID = 'vaildLeagueID'");

    $track = array ([0] = $_POST['track1'];
                    [1] = $_POST['track2'];
                    [2] = $_POST['track3'];
                    [3] = $_POST['track4'];
                    [4] = $_POST['track5'];
                    [5] = $_POST['track6'];
                    [6] = $_POST['track7'];
                    [7] = $_POST['track8'];
                    [8] = $_POST['track9'];
                    [9] = $_POST['track10'] );

    $info = mysql_fetch_array( $data );

    $i = '0';
    $min =  $info['minLeagueID'];
    $max =  $info['maxLeagueID'];

    while( $min != $max) {

        $updateTable = mysqli_query("UPDATE leagueTracks SET trackID = '$track[$counter]' WHERE leagueID = '$vaildLeagueID' AND leagueTracks = '$min' ");
        $i++;
    }
```

Code update - however it still doesn't update the table.

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT min(leagueTrackID) AS minLeagueID, max(leagueTrackID) AS maxLeagueID , leagueID , trackID FROM leagueTracks WHERE leagueID = 'vaildLeagueID'");

$track = array (

        0 => $_POST['track1'],
        1 => $_POST['track2'],
        2 => $_POST['track3'],
        3 => $_POST['track4'],
        4 => $_POST['track5'],
        5 => $_POST['track6'],
        6 => $_POST['track7'],
        7 => $_POST['track8'],
        8 => $_POST['track9'],
        9 => $_POST['track10']

  );

$info = mysql_fetch_array( $data );

$i = '0';
$min =  $info['minLeagueID'];
$max =  $info['maxLeagueID'];

while( $min != $max ) {

    $updateTable = mysqli_query("UPDATE leagueTracks SET trackID = '$track[$i]' WHERE leagueID = '$vaildLeagueID' AND leagueTrackID = '$min' ");
    $i++;
    $min++;
}
```

This is the form structure I'm currently using, copied ten times for each input.

```
<div class="form-group" align="center">

    <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">
        <h5>Track 1</h5>
    </label>

    <div class="form-group col-lg-8">

        <select name="track1" class="form-control col-lg-12" style="background:#e1e1e1;">

            <option value="0">Select a Track</option>
            <option value="1">Track 1</option>
            <option value="2">Track 2</option>
            <option value="3">Track 3</option>
            <option value="4">Track 4</option>
            <option value="5">Track 5</option>
            <option value="6">Track 6</option>
            <option value="7">Track 7</option>

        </select>

    </div>
</div>
```

Notice that I am calling this form "track1". Should this be name="track[]" or something?

As you can see in the image the WHERE and AND functionality isn't highlighted in red like the SELECT and from, meaning there is problem with how it is structured.

Below is the current error:

[image: SQL Error]

Comment: What is the problem exactly ? By the way, `while( $min != $max)` is infinite if $min or $max never change inside of it

Comment: Where is $counter? i think it should be $i. Also what are $min and $max?

Comment: @ClémentMalet - yep I spotted that after posting the message, I have now added a $min++; within the loop. Thanks for pointing it out any how.

Comment: @YatinMistry min is leagueTrackID min value so 140 whereas max is max leagueTrackID so 150. Then when the code runs $min has +1 added to it so it goes 141, 142, 143. Therefore updating the correct row within the table.

Comment: @user3393730: Regarding the image you had attached, it's not an error in your code, but in how Sublime interprets it. A potential issue that I do see is your use of "mysqli_query" in the update loop and "mysql_query" in the SELECT query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using this select dropdown multiple time like below and submit from

After Submit

```
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST["track"]);
```

You will get results

```
   Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)
```

Your Form

```
    <select name="track[]" class="form-control col-lg-12" style="background:#e1e1e1; ">
            <option value="0">Select a Track</option>
            <option value="1">Track 1</option>
           .....
    </select>


    <select name="track[]" class="form-control col-lg-12" style="background:#e1e1e1; ">
            <option value="0">Select a Track</option>
            <option value="1">Track 1</option>
           .....
    </select>
    .........
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

1. Remove **$track array** from code
2. Add this in your query **$_POST["track"][$i]**

   Your Query

   ```
   $updateTable = mysqli_query("UPDATE leagueTracks SET trackID = '".$_POST["track"][$i]."' WHERE leagueID = '$vaildLeagueID' AND leagueTrackID = '$min' ");
   ```

Comment: This didn't work, however, does each track input in the form need to be set to following: name="track1" , "track2" or track[]?

Comment: I am not getting. Can you explain in detail?

Comment: I have updated the question to try and explain.

Comment: I have added the code you suggested however, from the WHERE clause it isn't highlighted as it should be.  From what I know, it looks like it is placing everything after the first '" to be included.

Comment: What error or query generating after update? Show result query.

Comment: Updated question to show the problem with the SQL Query.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you define multiple array values - I'm not quite sure where you've got that from but the correct syntax is this:

```
$track = array(
    0 => $_POST['track1'],
    1 => $_POST['track2'],
    // etc
);
```

The indentation is optional, but the `[]` around the key, just using `=` as the assignment operator and `;` between array entries are all incorrect.

Also from your SQL query it looks like `leagueID` (or at the very least, `legueID`, which I assume is meant to be the same thing) is an integer since you're doing `MIN` and `MAX` on it, but then you finish off the query with `WHERE legueID = 'vaildLeagueID'` which is a string, so won't match anything (unless you're just substituting an actual number with descriptive text).

Comment: I have now updated my code with the array you posted, which has stopped a error being thrown, however, how do then receive and update the table?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your mySQL query is correctly selecting what you want it to? I can see a number of misspellings of "league".

Additionally, you'll want to do something like $min++ inside the loop, otherwise min will never = max.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to define array:

```
    $track = array();
    $track[0] = $_POST['track1'];
    $track[1] = $_POST['track2'];
    $track[2] = $_POST['track3'];
    .
    .
    .
    so on
```

and the other is :

```
    $track = array($_POST['track1'],$_POST['track2'],........);
```